# Double check e-mail validation at the Django backend

Tags: python, django, validation

Considering that a user can disable JavaScript in the browser, how can I proceed with a "double check" for e-mail validation in the **Django** backend (specifically, to prevent register using Webmail [GMail, Hotmail and so on])? Thanks.

Comment: Use form validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it inside your forms.py(you have to create that file) app like this

```py
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean_email(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email.endswith('@gmail.com'):  # etc.
            raise forms.ValidationError('This is not a valid email')
        return email
```

[Here you can find more about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: The list of blocked, webmail address are very large... Could I append the suffixes side-by-side, in this case, beside the @gmail one? Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like this: Have a list with everything you want to block and then change the condition to check if the ending is inside the blocked list. Did it help you ?

Comment: @pcbillions4 you can get the email extension with various ways like .split('@')[-1] etc.

Comment: Do endswith() support three or more values for comparisson? What if I want to stick with the code above, how to iterate over a dozen of email suffixes? Once again, thanks! cc @Iakovos Belonias

Comment: you can do something like this email_domain = email.split('@')[-1], that will get the email domain name, email_domain = 'gmail.com'. Then you have a list with the blokced_emails = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'mail.com'], then you do something like this, if email_domain in blocked_emails: raise Error(where Error you replace with the proper django error)

Comment: @pcbillions4 check my answer to see if it helped you